# not able to use 2d sprite shape controller in unity 3d core

Tags: unity-game-engine, game-development

I was trying to make a 2d platformer using unity 3d environment so that I can have a terrain in the background and a 2d player in front of the camera with a platform. I wanted to use unity's 2d sprite shape for the platform but I am not able to use it.

I have installed the package and also have done everything I could.